# piano keys sticking seemingly randomly - can't figure out why

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a visual keyboard controlled by midi instrument input in Unity. My method of feedback for a key press is to change the alpha of the key's colour to 0.5 to show it is currently being pressed. Normally the key's colour is reset to it's original after the key is stopped being pressed, however seemingly randomly a key will 'stick', staying transparent until it is pressed again. Here is the part of the class responsible for this:

```
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    Color tmp1, tmp2;

    SpriteRenderer[] keys = new SpriteRenderer[32];

    void Start () {
        for (int i = 48; i < 80; i++) {
            keys [i - 48] = GameObject.Find (i.ToString()).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
        }
    }

    void Update () {

        for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
            if (MidiMaster.GetKeyDown (j + 48)) {
                tmp1 = keys [j].color;
                tmp1.a = 0.5f;
                keys [j].color = tmp1;
            }

            if (MidiMaster.GetKeyUp (j + 48)) {
                tmp2 = keys [j].color;
                tmp2.a = 1f;
                keys [j].color = tmp2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just as a note, the reason `j` is increased by 48 in the `GetKeyUp()` and `GetKeyDown()` calls is that the MIDI value of the first key on my keyboard is 48, not 0.

What part of this code is causing the random sticking?

Comment: if you decrease the loop size to say... j<5. Do any of those 5 keys still stick?

Comment: yes, lowering j does not change the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the problem lies in MidiMaster.GetKeyUp/Down.

If MidiMaster.GetKeyUp/Down works same way as Unity Input.GetKeyUp/Down, the methods only return true during the frame the event occurred.

The MidiMaster in https://github.com/keijiro/MidiJack has a method similar to Input.GetKey (which tells if the key is held down). Perhaps you could use that:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
    tmp1 = keys[j].color;
    // The value ranges from 0.0 (note-off) to 1.0 (maximum velocity)
    tmp1.a = MidiMaster.GetKey(j + 48) > 0f ? 0.5f : 1f;
    keys[j].color = tmp1;
}
```